# Finding studs through weatherboard

Tags: exterior, studs

I'm trying to install this hose reel below [image: HoseReel]

onto my weatherboarded exterior wall.

Do I necessarily need to remove some boarding to find the inner studs?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a stud finder?

Comment: @SDsolar Actually I think I'm seeing them.. but I was afraid I was only seeing the furrings...